# Why is it needed to use file-descriptors for returning UDP or TCP traffic in bash?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I am aware that one needs to use file-descriptors in order to read from TCP or UDP sockets. For example:

```
exec 3<>/dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161; echo -n "302902010104067075626c6963a01c02047f14ec98020100020100300e300c06082b060102010105000500" | xxd -r -p >&3; read -n 1 -t 0.2 <&3
```

However, why isn't it possible to read from sockets directly, e.g:

```
echo -n "302902010104067075626c6963a01c02047f14ec98020100020100300e300c06082b060102010105000500" | xxd -r -p > /dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161; read -n 1 -t 0.2 < /dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161
```

Comment: I suspect something related to buffering; in the first case, file descriptor 3 is open throughout the process. In the second, the socket is closed immediately after you write to it, so the data will not be available when you reopen the socket to read from it.

Comment: That sounds more like the issue is that you need somewhere for the incoming data to go (the open local socket) and less that the data will not be available when you reopen the socket (because it was flushed). Especially since you don't know how long it will take the incoming data to appear.

Answer (score 1):

A socket is a single file descriptor that can be used in two directions. The usual file operators in Bash, `<` and `>` only work on one file descriptor in one direction.

You could overwrite an existing descriptor, like stdin, and then use that file descriptor number explicitly. But this is basically equivalent to just using a separate descriptor.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading. The `exec` command will work just fine without a `<>` redirection; either `3>/dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161` or `3</dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161` will do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
echo -n "$hex_string" | xxd -r -p > /dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161
read -n 1 -t 0.2 < /dev/udp/192.0.2.1/161
```

The result will be that a UDP socket will be opened to port 161 using some ephemeral port (such as 42297) for sending, then a message will be written to port 161, and then the socket will be closed. Subsequently, another UDP socket will be opened to port 161 with a different ephemeral source port (such as 48546), and then the script will wait for input on that socket. On the listening end, a packet will be received from port 42297, and presumably a response sent also to port 42297. But the client is not listening to port 42297; depending on the speed with which the response is sent, it may or may not be listening to port 48546, but there's no way for the server side to know that.

For TCP, the situation is similar and somewhat clearer, but equally useless. The echo command sets up a TCP connection, sends some data, and closes the connection. The server side will receive the packet and then immediately receive a disconnect indication, so it will not be able to reply.

Using the first example, where the connection is opened and assigned to a file descriptor, the socket will not be closed until after both the `echo` and the `read` have completed (and whatever other commands are processed in that shell). With a persistent socket, there is no communication problem.